# Why is set of elliptic curves Zariski open in parametric space $\mathbb{P}^9$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, zariski-topology

I'm having trouble seeing why set of elliptic curves is Zariski open in the parametric space $\mathbb{P}^9$ of all cubics. I will be grateful to receive any help on this.

Comment: The set of non-smooth cubic is clearly Zariski closed.

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$? It isn't clear to me (I think it is false) that having a $K$-rational point is a Zariski closed condition?